# coffeescript - Dashing dashboard not showing correct icon

Tags: widget, dashing

I created a Dashing widget and I am having errors displaying the correct icon on the dashboard. The procedure checks for a value coming from a text file and if it's over 28 it should display a warning icon, but it ends showing a check icon. I am using the if clause below

```
  @accessor 'arrow', ->
  if @get(parseInt('tatint')) > 28 then 'icon-warning-sign' else 'icon-check'
```

Translated -

```
this.accessor('arrow', function() {
  if (this.get(parseInt('tatint')) > 28) {
    return 'icon-warning-sign';
  } else {
    return 'icon-check';
  }
})
```

;

Thanks in advance

Comment: (1) Is that your real indentation? (2) What does `@get` do? Shouldn't you be passing a string to `@get` and applying `parseInt` to what it returns?

Comment: (1) no, the indentation on my file seems fine, (2) I tried that initially, borrowing from some other Dashing modules, but it didn't work, but with a different "error", as the font awesome icons were not rendered correctly. I will try your suggestion again and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: `parseInt('tatint')` will give you `NaN` every time and I doubt `@get(NaN)` will do anything useful. `@get('tatint')` OTOH will probably lookup the named attribute and return its value.

Comment: I think my problem is that I have an array of items being passed to a table display, this way @get is not able to get a single value and it's returned undefined.